# Getting error string was not recognized as a valid using c#

Tags: c#

when i am try to change date format from csv file 3/1/2021-3/31/2021 to Mar-01-2021-Mar-31-2021 getting error please help me solve the issue.

```
                       foreach (DataRow dr in dtDataTable.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ListInputDateColumns.Contains(dtDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName))
                {
                    if(dtDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName == "Period")
                    {
                        sw.Write(dr[i] = Convert.ToDateTime(dtDataTable.Rows[i][dtDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString()]).ToString("MMM-dd-yyyy-MMM-dd-yyyy"));//Here i am getting error
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sw.Write(dr[i] = Convert.ToDateTime(dtDataTable.Rows[i][dtDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString()]).ToString("MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));
                    }
                    //sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
                }
                //sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
                sw.Write(",");
            }
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Its unable to parse the input string as its not actually a date, its _two_ dates joined by a hyphen. You'll need to do a bit more work to get the result you need, get the column name, split it at the hyphen, that will give you two strings that _are_ dates, parse those and you can then create the output in the format you want.

Comment: `DateTime` has no format, it's a binary value. There's nothing to convert. The code you posted does nothing at best, returning the original value. If the current user's locale doesn't match the US-style date format, it will throw a conversion error

Comment: @deepak *remove* any attempt to convert what doesn't need converting - the entire `dr[i] = Convert.ToDateTime(...` expression is meaningless. If the field value is a DateTime already, all you need to do is `sw.Write("{0:MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}",dr[i]);`. The US-style date string would have to be parsed using the `en-US` culture though. It would be a lot better to use the ISO8601 format

Comment: I think you might be overusing the 'i' variable. Is it a reference for column or row? I expect this is one of several problems.

Comment: Hello  Panagiotis Kanavos , sw.Write("{0:MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}",dr[i]); this will work for only single date like 3/31/2021 but to convert this  3/1/2021-3/31/2021 its wont change output is same like 3/1/2021-3/31/2021

Comment: Anyone please help me to convert 3/23/2021 7:01:36 PM to 23-Mar-2021 7:01:36 PM      i tried this one sw.Write("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}", dr[i]); still its not converting giving same output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse that string by splitting it by the delimiter and then parse each token to `DateTime`. Then you can convert it back to string with the desired format:

```
string targetFormat = "MMM-dd-yyyy";
string s = " 3/1/2021-3/31/2021";
string[] tokens = s.Split('-');
if(tokens.Length == 2)
{
    bool validFrom = DateTime.TryParse(tokens[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime fromDate);
    bool validTo = DateTime.TryParse(tokens[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime toDate);
    if (validFrom && validTo)
    {
        string result = $"{fromDate.ToString(targetFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}-{toDate.ToString(targetFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}";           
    }
}
```

Comment: hii same method i used to convert 3/23/2021  7:01:36 PM to 23-Mar-2021 7:01:36 PM (dd-MMM-yyyy) but its returning same input not convert to dd-MMM-yyyy

Comment: string dateformat = "MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
                            string InputData = Convert.ToString(dr[i]);
                            bool Date = DateTime.TryParse(InputData, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime CustDate);
                            string DateData = $"{CustDate.ToString(dateformat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}";
                            dr[i] = DateData;
                            sw.Write(dr[i]);

Comment: string dateformat = "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"; //here i gave time portion also

Comment: This is how my output written in csv file :  3/23/2021 19:01 but i can see this kind also 3/23/2021  7:01:36 PM why i am getting like this

Comment: are u free now, its really i need i am struck here

Answer (score 0):

OK, we can do this in one line of code if you want, but it gets pretty ugly as far as readability goes.  For a one liner, simply change this line:

`sw.Write(dr[i] = Convert.ToDateTime(dtDataTable.Rows[i][dtDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString()]).ToString("MMM-dd-yyyy-MMM-dd-yyyy"));//Here i am getting error`

to

`sw.Write(dr[i] = Convert.ToDateTime((dtDataTable.Rows[i][dtDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString()]).Substring(0, (dtDataTable.Rows[i][dtDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString()]).IndexOf('-'))).ToString("MMM-dd-yyyy") + "-" + Convert.ToDateTime((dtDataTable.Rows[i][dtDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString()]).Substring((dtDataTable.Rows[i][dtDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString()]).IndexOf('-') + 1)).ToString("MMM-dd-yyyy");`

but for maintainability, I would recommend creating a quick method for parsing "Period" like this

`string ParsePeriod(string period)`
`{`
  `DateTime from = Convert.ToDateTime(period.Substring(0, period.IndexOf('-')));`
  `DateTime to = Convert.ToDateTime(period.Substring(period.IndexOf('-') + 1));`
  `return from.ToString("MMM-dd-yyyy") + "-" + to.ToString("MMM-dd-yyyy");`
`}`

then call it like this by changing this:

`sw.Write(dr[i] = Convert.ToDateTime(dtDataTable.Rows[i][dtDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString()]).ToString("MMM-dd-yyyy-MMM-dd-yyyy"));//Here i am getting error`

to this:

`sw.Write(dr[i] = ParsePeriod(Convert.ToString(dtDataTable.Rows[i][dtDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString()])));`

I trust this solves your problem. ;-)

Comment: This i am getting error 
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: You may have to convert the value going into ParsePeriod.  I'll fix above.

Comment: can you help me to convert  3/23/2021 7:01:36 PM to 23-Mar-2021 7:01:36 PM

Comment: i tried this one sw.Write("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}", dr[i]); still its not converting